# Programmatically create and place a nav menu in a theme location?

Tags: menus, themes

A client has numerous subsites and would like to include a 'global menu' within the packaged theme. I've got a registered location `global-menu` and I've got it populated with links in `functions.php`.

Which action do I use to place that menu inside of the theme location?

Comment: What do you mean you've got "it" populated? Menu Locations and Menu Objects are two separate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) displays a navigation menu and `'theme_location'` can target a menu registered with [`register_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/).

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'global-menu'
) );
```